# How to sort an array of numbers to make scattered numbers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

There is an array of arrays of numbers. Some numbers are repeats 2 to 6 times. How can I scatter numbers that so repeated numbers don't stand together?
Each internal array can have maximum 4 numbers

```
[
  [54, 23, 23, 23],
  [12, 12, 66, 66],
  [66, 66, 08, 43],
  [43, 43, 99, 00],
  [32, 54, 27, 73],
  [93, 51, 71, 39]
]
```

Comment: First, you have to define exactly what you mean by *"don't stand together"*

Comment: @user3386109 for example, stand 4-9 elements further from the same number

Comment: *"Some numbers are repeats 2 to 6 times."*. What does it mean? 2 to 6 times in the full matrix?

Comment: *don't stand together* means not adjacent with row as well as column?

Comment: @FarukHossain yes

Comment: means only after the same number in 1 dimension. i.e. the matrix should be transformed to line of numbers, sort numbers, and then back to the matrix with arrays up to 4 numbers (i.e. only last array can be less than 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. It took long time to solve this question.

Here is an approach. Although there might be several techniques for this problem but I think this solution will be easy to understand.

1. Sort all the elements taking into another single array.
2. Define r = 0, c = 0.
3. Pick each element from array and then try to place it in the matrix. If it is not possible then try next position.

   ```
   int n = matrix.size();
   int m = matrix[0].size();

   vector<int> arr;
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
           arr.push_back(matrix[i][j]);
       }
   }
   sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
   int dr[] = {-1, 0, 1, 0}; /// 4 sides
   int dc[] = {0, 1, 0, -1}; /// 4 sides
   int r = 0, c = 0;
   int new_matrix[n][m];
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
           new_matrix[i][j] = -1;
   }
   bool vis[n][m] = {false};
   for(int k = 0; k < n*m; ) {
       int cur_num = arr[k];
       bool check = false;
       if(!vis[r][c]) {
           for(int p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
               int adjr = r + dr[p];
               int adjc = c + dc[p];
               if(adjr < 0 || adjr >= n || adjc < 0 || adjc >= m) continue;
               if(new_matrix[adjr][adjc] == cur_num) check = true;
           }
           if(check == false) {
               new_matrix[r][c] = cur_num;
               vis[r][c] = true;
               k++;
           }
       }
       c++;
       if(c >= m) r++, c = c % m;
       if(r >= n) r = r % n;
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
           cout<<new_matrix[i][j]<<" ";
       }
       cout<<endl;
   }
   ```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: It took long time to translate it to JS))
Really, thank you! This solution solves the task

Comment: btw, this solution sorts by rows and columns too. After sort rows, just need rotate the matrix and do the same